# Snake game : Movement of snake

Tags: c++

I am a beginner at c++ and only familiar with basic c++ libraries. I have to build a console based snake game as my project. While trying to build it I have an issue with the movement as I am not able to move the snake in the console. I have used  library and have taken input from user as input. After that I tried to change the dimensions of the head of the snake and move it but it is just taking input and exiting the code without any movement. Following is my project code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include<conio.h>
int height=21, width=50;
int x_cordinate=width/2,y_cordinate=height/2;
using namespace std;
void layout();
void snake_movement();
int main(){
    bool game=true;
    while(game==true){
        layout();
        snake_movement();
    }
    return 0;
}
void layout(){
    system("cls");
    int eating_X,eating_y;
    srand(time(NULL));
    eating_X=rand()%width-2;
    eating_y=rand()%height;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2*width; i++)
    {
        if (i==49)
        {
            cout<<"+"<<endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                cout<<"|";
                for (int k = 0; k < 48; k++)
                    {
                        if (j==y_cordinate && k==48/2)
                        {
                            cout<<"O";
                        }
                        else if (k==eating_X && j==eating_y)
                        {
                            cout<<"*";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout<<" ";
                        }
                    }
            cout<<"|"<<endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"+";
        }
    }  
    snake_movement();

}

void snake_movement(){

    switch (getch())
    {
    case 'w':
        y_cordinate++;
        break;
    case 'a':
        x_cordinate--;
        break;
    case 's':
        y_cordinate--;
        break;    
    case 'd':
        x_cordinate++;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this for an assignment? If so, is the snake game a requirement or a choice? It seems a bit complex for a beginner project. Working with the console in a live-fashion is a bit more difficult.

Comment: If it is a game you should have a `while(true)` loop somewhere in your code to keep going. As I see it right now your program ends after  `snake_movement()` is done, which is a switch case statement that executes only once.

Comment: @VarunNayak done that editing sir but the snake just moves up and down and even that occurs if i keep pressing the key. It does not go left or right neither it keeps on movement.

Comment: I would suggest breaking down the assignment into smaller chunks and then reaching out for help with the implementation of those individual components.

Comment: @VarunNayak ok sir thank you very much